# A set of $n$ vectors is a basis if and only if...

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Every set of $n+1$ vectors in an $n$-dimensional vector space $V$ is linearly dependent. A set of $n$ vectors in $V$ is a basis if and only if it is linearly independent, or, alternatively, if and only if every vector in $V$ is a linear combination of elements of the set. (Halmos pg 14)

I have a question about the second part. If every vector is a linear combination of elements of the list doesn't that make them dependent? So how could it be a basis?

Comment: Probably the dimension of $V$ is fixed by $n$. Then a spanning set of $n$ vectors is linearly independent.

Comment: The definition you quote has a couple of problems and isn't correct. Surely Halmos didn't write that. Please fix. Also, you don't mention the dimension of the space, and that's important here. A set of $2$ vectors in $\Bbb R^3$ can be linearly independent but will never be a basis for $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: In finite dimension $n$ all set of $n$ linearly independent vectors is a base.

Comment: Here is the full theorem... Every set of n+1 vectors in an n-dimensional vector space V in linearly dependent. A set of n vectors in V is a basis if and only if it is linearly independent, or, alternatively, if and only if every vector in V is a linear combination of elements of the set.

Comment: Yes — *in an $n$-dimensional space*. Much better :)

Comment: Thanks so much everyone :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to read carefully.  It begins by saying "a set of $n$ vectors".  Let's call that set of $n$ vectors $S$. Then $S$ is a subset of $V$.  So part of this assertion says:

> > every vector in $V$ is a linear combination of elements of $S$.

If a vector $v$ in $S$ is a linear combination of members of $S$ other than $V$ itself, then $S$ is linearly dependent.  But it doesn't say every vector in $S$; it says every vector in $V$, so that does not make $S$ linearly dependent.  It makes $V$, not $S$, linearly dependent.

Comment: Thank you so much  :) I see now I was mixing up the vectors in the vector space and the vectors of the set.

Comment: I think the statement in the question was right, Michael. Since V is an n-dimensional vector space, a set of n vectors is linearly independent iff it is a spanning set, so there is no need to check for both conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Let $S=\{v_1,\dots,v_k\}$ be a basis for the $k$-dimensional vector space $V$.

What the second part says is that if $v\in V$, then $v=\sum_\limits{i=1}^k c_iv_i$ for some $c_i$.

Each individual $v_i$ **cannot** be constructed from the remaining elements of $S$, $|S|=k$, hence $s$ is a basis.